# Why is Esperanto in the source code but not in the Settings menu?

Tags: android, internationalization

It seems like Android uses ICU and CLDR for date-time format localisation, and CLDR contains EO. ICU import the data from CLDR. The Android language files seems to be located at (which does not contain EO)

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/res/res/

but it looks like it was added by this merge request back in 2012:

https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/build/+/30931

How come then I cannot see Esperanto under the language section in the Settings app on Android 8? Why is it not being generated into the `core/res/res` folder if it is in the locales_full.mk file? Is there something I am missing in the source code or is it simply a matter of it not being translated? If the later, where is this translation process (of languages in general) taking place?

Comment: I apologize if this is in the wrong SE. If wrong, please move it if possible.

Comment: I think I possibly have found it.... https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-9.0.0_r1/core/res/res/values/locale_config.xml  maybe, but I still don't understand where the language files actually are...

Comment: "How come then I cannot see Esperanto under the language section in the Settings app on Android 8?" -- the decision of what languages to list in Settings is up to the device manufacturer. In part, that will be based on what languages the device manufacturer has translated its own apps to, which in turn may be based on the intended market for the device.

Comment: @CommonsWare Lets say it's just a random producer making stock Android phones. The localisation/translation must be made at some stage. Basically where is Android system langague translated? Do device maker restrict available languages to only those they have translated their own stock-loaded pre-installed apps into??

Comment: "Do device maker restrict available languages to only those they have translated their own stock-loaded pre-installed apps into?" -- yes, usually. After all, their device would be considered to be broken otherwise (Settings claims that Klingon is supported, but pre-loaded apps crash or show English or something when the user chooses Klingon).

Comment: Could it be the case that most settings are now being processed via Google Play Services rather than accessing Android system settings directly? I wouldn't be at all surprised if that were the case. It might be that GPS is restricting the options to what GPS itself can support.

Comment: @Topperfalkon Initially I cannot see how that makes sense, to have geo-restricted language selection. As I can for example select Korean in Sweden and Norwegian in Japan. Also "to what GPS itself can support" that doesn't make any sense at all to me. GPS is not bound by any specific spoken language. The GPS protocol is standardized and universal.

Comment: @Max sorry I haven't replied sooner. I meant GPS as shorthand for Google Play Services having mentioned it in full once if that's a source of confusion. Android's base OS may support Esperanto, but it's entirely possible that on 'stock Android' most locale settings are being provided via Google Play Services, which may not have the same support.